# Unit test a controller action that makes calls to async relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I have two models, `Program` and `Project`. A `Program` has many `Project`s.

```
App.Program = DS.Model.extend
  projects: DS.hasMany 'project', async: true

App.Project = DS.Model.extend
  program: DS.belongsTo 'program'
```

I have an `ArrayController` responsible for displaying all the projects in a program. Each project rendered has a `destroy` link (a simple action on the `ArrayController`).

```
App.ProjectsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  needs: 'program'
  program: Ember.computed.alias 'controllers.program.model'

  actions:
    destroy: (project) ->
      @get('program.projects').then (projects) ->
        projects.removeObject(project) # how can I test this line?
      @get('program').save()
      project.destroyRecord()
```

Since the relationships are async, calling `program.get('projects')` returns a promise.

I'm using Firebase (and `emberFire`) as my backend, which stores relationships like

```
programs: {
  programId: {
    projects: {
      projectId: true
    }
  }
}
projects: {
  program: 'programId'
}
```

I'm using `ember-qunit` and `sinon` for a stub/mock library. My first attempt at testing this makes really heavy use of `sinon.spy()`.

```
moduleFor 'controller:projects.index', 'Unit - Controller - Projects Index',
  needs: ['controller:program']

test 'actions - destroy', ->
  ctrl = @subject()
  programCtrl = ctrl.get('controllers.program')
  project1 = Em.Object.create(title: 'Project #1', destroyRecord: sinon.spy())
  project2 = Em.Object.create(title: 'Project #2', destroyRecord: sinon.spy())
  projects = Em.Object.create(removeObject: sinon.spy())
  program = Em.Object.create
    title: 'Program #1'
    projects:
      then: sinon.stub().yields(projects)
    save: sinon.spy()

  Ember.run ->
    programCtrl.set 'model', program
    ctrl.send 'destroy', project1
    ok(program.projects.then.calledOnce, 'Removes the project from the program')
    ok(program.save.calledOnce, 'Saves the program')
    ok(project1.destroyRecord.calledOnce, 'Destroys the project')
```

I'm creating new Ember objects, since there is no clear way for me to instantiate an instance of my models in my tests (at least that I know about). Every function that gets called in the action uses a `sinon.spy()` so I can make assertions that they did in fact get called.

Coming from a Rails background this seems like a lot of test code for four relatively simple lines of CoffeeScript, which leads me to believe I might be going about this the wrong way.

**Either way, my overall question is this:**

How can I test (using sinon, or any other way) that `removeObject()` was in fact called on `program.projects` in the async callback function?

Also, is there an easier way for me to stub my models without creating new Ember objects in every test, in such a way that I can make assertions like I am above?